# Почему не работает кроссдоменный Ajax в Firefox?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Во всех браузерах кроме Firefox, Ajax работает. Код ниже.
В Firefox выдает следующее:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса наhttps://ХТМЛ.html. Это может быть исправлено путем перемещения ресурса в тот же домен или включением CORS.

На сервере откуда берется html, в htaccess прописано:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

```
var urlPage = 'https://страница,где должна происходить магия', 
      queryLink = 'https://ссылка с айди/?id=', 
      linkPartners = 'https://ссылка на html на сервере.html';


$.ajax({

  url: linkPartners,
  success: function(html){

    if (urlPage == window.location.href) {
        $(".orange-box .blink").html(html).css({
          "background": "none",
          "padding": "0"
        });
        $(".orange-box").css('background', 'none');
        $(".ob-content").css('background', 'none');
    };

    $('.table-partners tbody a').attr('href',function(){
       linkSub = this.href + $('#inner_link').data('link');
       return linkSub;
    });
  }
});




$.ajax({    


  url: queryLink + $('#inner_link').data('link'),
  success: function(html){


    if(urlPage == window.location.href ) {
      if (html != "") {

        var objJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
        if (objJSON != null) {
          var balance = objJSON.sum;     

          if (balance != null) {
              $('.profileData h4').append('<div class="bal-left">Действительны до <a href="#" target="_blank">1.10.2015</a>: <strong>' + balance + ' </strong></div>');
              return;
          } 
        }
      };
 }
 $('.profileData h4').append('<span style="display:none;"></span>');
}
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно включить CORS на сервере, как собственно и написано в ошибке.

Если у вас например ASP MVC на OWIN, то там не достаточно аттрибута типа:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://...", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Нужно в регистрации добавить:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай вообще без jQuery, вот тебе пример, переделай под себя. будет работать.

```
function r(){ 

        var url = ''+HOST+'';

        var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

        var xhr = new XHR();

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            options = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            alert(options.otvet); // выводим данные.

        }

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            // alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
            //console.log( 'Ошибка ' + this.status);
        }

        xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: если помогло пометь как правильный ответ